# Teradata recurring payment patterns

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using a customer period level data to find recurring patterns of the transactions they have done.

What I want is to find if the customer is doing recurring payments of the amounts +-10% either weekly, fortnightly or monthly.

I am restricted to Teradata for this, so I am using self join with the same table defining join on accounts and channel through which the transaction is going. As the channel can vary, there can be multiple transactions in a day so that filter on join is required. I am also giving a loose window as people can pay a day after or before also.

The query I am using currently is like this:

```
`
create multiset table weekly as 
(
sel a.*, b.*, c.*
from table1 a
join table1 b
on a.account = b.account and a.channel = b.channel
join table1 c
on a.account = c.account and a.channel = c.channel
where c.date between b.date + 6 and b.date + 9 and b.amount between 0.9*(c.amount) and 1.1*(c.amount) 
and b.date between a.date + 6 and a.date + 9 and a.amount between 0.9*(b.amount) and 1.1*(b.amount)
)
with data
primary index(account)
'
```

Is there any other efficient way of doing is becuase I am able to max join 3 self joins and I need more than 3 recurrence to confirm its weekly? I can migrate this data to R and then build some algo on it but data size is around 40 million.

Comment: How many account/channel combinations exists? And what's the average & maximum rows per combination? Of course this query might create huge (intermediate) result sets, does it fail due to spool space restrictions or is it consuming too much resources? What's the PI of the base table, `account`?

Comment: Instead of doing all the self-joins, could you add calculations to your main select, and then filter on those?

Comment: @dnoeth For one account the average transactions per day are 9 and 3 channel are there to it can either all be through a single channel or any combination of channels. Its consuming too much resources. Primary index is account whereas the secondary index's are channel, amount and date.

Comment: @Andrew Can you please elaborate a little what kind of calculations you are referring to here?

Comment: Something like `select a.*, (a.date + 6) as DatePlus6, (a.date + 9) as DatePlus9 from table1 a where a.date between DatePlus6 and DatePlus9`.

Comment: That is also eventually equally resource internsive as first one has to create columns and then go for self joins!